# How plot methan maps from OCO-2/Tropomi NETCDF4 files using Xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

This is a follow up question to the following question: [How to process the Time variables of OCO-2/Tropomi NETCDF4 files using Xarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261579/how-to-process-the-time-variables-of-oco-2-tropomi-netcdf4-files-using-xarray)

I am working on the same data and have some problems understanding the format.

I would like to plot a map of 'xch4' as function of latitude and longitude for a given time.

I would assume that I could define a new structure for a given time:

new_ds=ds.isel(time=0)

and then plot xch4 for this structure

new_ds.xch4.plot()

but this does not work.

I am somewhat new to Xarray, so any help would be greatly appreciate.

The code and the output is given as:

```
import xarray as xr
ds=xr.open_dataset('ESACCI-GHG-L2-CH4-CO-TROPOMI-WFMD-20200430-fv1.nc')
ds
```

The returned output is:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                 (corners_dim: 4, layer_dim: 20, level_dim: 21, sounding_dim: 549041)
Dimensions without coordinates: corners_dim, layer_dim, level_dim, sounding_dim
Data variables:
    time                    (sounding_dim) datetime64[ns] ...
    latitude                (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    longitude               (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    solar_zenith_angle      (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    sensor_zenith_angle     (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    azimuth_difference      (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    xch4                    (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    xch4_uncertainty        (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    xco                     (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    xco_uncertainty         (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    quality_flag            (sounding_dim) int32 ...
    pressure_levels         (sounding_dim, level_dim) float32 ...
    pressure_weight         (sounding_dim, layer_dim) float32 ...
    ch4_profile_apriori     (sounding_dim, layer_dim) float32 ...
    xch4_averaging_kernel   (sounding_dim, layer_dim) float32 ...
    co_profile_apriori      (sounding_dim, layer_dim) float32 ...
    xco_averaging_kernel    (sounding_dim, layer_dim) float32 ...
    orbit_number            (sounding_dim) int32 ...
    scanline                (sounding_dim) int32 ...
    ground_pixel            (sounding_dim) int32 ...
    latitude_corners        (sounding_dim, corners_dim) float32 ...
    longitude_corners       (sounding_dim, corners_dim) float32 ...
    altitude                (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    apparent_albedo         (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    land_fraction           (sounding_dim) int32 ...
    cloud_parameter         (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    h2o_column              (sounding_dim) float32 ...
    h2o_column_uncertainty  (sounding_dim) float32 ...
Attributes:
    title:                     TROPOMI/WFMD XCH4 and XCO
    institution:               University of Bremen
    source:                    TROPOMI L1B version 01.00.00
    history:                   2019 - product generated with WFMD
    tracking_id:               497532a4-fa32-406d-9f6e-52e87f527d47
    Conventions:               CF-1.6
    product_version:           v1.2
    summary:                   Weighting Function Modified DOAS (WFMD) was ad...
    keywords:                  satellite, Sentinel-5 Precursor, TROPOMI, atmo...
    id:                        ESACCI-GHG-L2-CH4-CO-TROPOMI-WFMD-20200430-fv1.nc
    naming_authority:          iup.uni-bremen.de
    keywords_vocabulary:       NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD)
    cdm_data_type:             point
    comment:                   These data were produced at the University of ...
    date_created:              20201030T124301Z
    creator_name:              University of Bremen, IUP, Oliver Schneising
    creator_email:             schneising@iup.physik.uni-bremen.de
    project:                   Climate Change Initiative - European Space Agency
    geospatial_lat_min:        -90
    geospatial_lat_max:        90
    geospatial_lat_units:      degree_north
    geospatial_lon_min:        -180
    geospatial_lon_max:        180
    geospatial_lon_units:      degree_east
    geospatial_vertical_min:   0
    geospatial_vertical_max:   100000
    time_coverage_start:       20200430T000000Z
    time_coverage_end:         20200430T235959Z
    time_coverage_duration:    P1D
    time_coverage_resolution:  P1D
    standard_name_vocabulary:  NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Metadata Conv...
    license:                   ESA CCI Data Policy: free and open access
    platform:                  Sentinel-5 Precursor
    sensor:                    TROPOMI
    spatial_resolution:        7km x 7km at nadir (typically)
```

I then try:

```
new_ds=ds.isel(time=0)
```

and the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/au159666/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1959, in isel
    indexers = drop_dims_from_indexers(indexers, self.dims, missing_dims)
  File "/Users/au159666/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/utils.py", line 767, in drop_dims_from_indexers
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: dimensions {'time'} do not exist. Expected one or more of Frozen(SortedKeysDict({'sounding_dim': 549041, 'level_dim': 21, 'layer_dim': 20, 'corners_dim': 4}))
```

I also try the suggestion from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261579/how-to-process-the-time-variables-of-oco-2-tropomi-netcdf4-files-using-xarray):

```
ds.swap_dims({"sounding_dim": "time"})
new_ds=ds.isel(time=0)
```

but still the result is the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/au159666/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1959, in isel
    indexers = drop_dims_from_indexers(indexers, self.dims, missing_dims)
  File "/Users/au159666/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/utils.py", line 767, in drop_dims_from_indexers
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: dimensions {'time'} do not exist. Expected one or more of Frozen(SortedKeysDict({'sounding_dim': 549041, 'level_dim': 21, 'layer_dim': 20, 'corners_dim': 4}))
```

Comment: You might want to try my package ncplot, which can automatically create interactive plots of xarray datasets: https://pypi.org/project/ncplot/. But can you provide a link to the dataset? It seems somewhat non-standard. Longitude/Latitude/time are variables, not coordinates, which is why your code is failing.

Comment: I will try ncplot. The data can be found here: https://www.iup.uni-bremen.de/carbon_ghg/products/tropomi_wfmd/

Comment: I had a quick look at the data. It won't work with ncplot. Looks like you will have to restructure the data so that longitude, latitude and time are coordinates to get ncplot or xarray's built in plotting method to produce a map

Comment: Actually, looking at the data it doesn't seem well suited to xarray, which deals with gidded data ideally. Geopandas is probably the package to work with or just pandas

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the reason why the files were hard to open with Xarray was that they contain a point cloud and not gridded data. I therefore opened them with Nio instead and plotted them the following way:

```
import Nio
import mpl_scatter_density
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file=Nio.open_file('../L2-CH4-CO-TROPOMI-WFMD-202004/ESACCI-GHG-L2-CH4-CO-TROPOMI-WFMD-20200415-fv1.nc','r')
xch4=file.variables['xch4']
latitude=file.variables['latitude']
longitude=file.variables['longitude']
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='scatter_density')
ax.scatter_density(longitude, latitude, c=xch4, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu)
fig.savefig('methane.png')
```